# can logrotate skip postrotate script if no log rotation took place?

Tags: logrotate

I have configured logrotate to rotate only when the log file size is beyond a certain limit.
Some logrotate definitions have postrotate scripts which seem to run every time logrotate is invoked, no matter if the log file in question has been rotated or not.
Thus there is some processing going on even though logrotate does not need to change the log file.

Is there a way to skip the postrotate part if the log file has not been rotated?

Example Entry:

```
# global settings
size=3M
rotate 2
create
compress
delaycompress
include /etc/logrotate.d

# wtmp settings
/var/log/wtmp
{
   size=3M
   create 0664 root utmp
   rotate 1
}
```

and I run the following command to see what would happen:

```
logrotate -d -f /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Comment: Are you sure that `postrotate` is really running when no file was rotated? It shouldn't.

Comment: I have configured logwatch.conf with

Comment: I have configured logrotate.conf with `size=3M
rotate 2
create
compress
delaycompress
include /etc/logrotate.d
/var/log/wtmp {
    size=3M
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}
`  and running `logrotate -d -f /etc/logrotate.conf`  shows "_considering log /var/log/wtmp
  log needs rotating_"  although wtmp is way below 3M.  _/etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng_ has the same defaults and a postrotate script which says "_invoke-rc.d syslog-ng reload_"  which is always run by logrotate although /var/log/syslog is only a few hundred kB.

Comment: Option `-f` tells  logrotate to force the rotation.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the mistake. I did run `logrotate -d -f /etc/logrotate.conf` which forces the rotation even if the conditions do not match. If I run it without the `-f` option everything works as desired.